# Function that captures a copy of the loop counter in Rust

Tags: c++, rust

I have some C++ code that looks like this (simplified to the point of being useless, but I hope you get the idea). It fills a vector of functions in a loop and makes every function capture the loop counter by copy:

```
std::vector<std::function<int()>> v;
for(int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
   v.push_back([i]() {return i;});
}

for(auto f: v) {
   std::cout << f() << "\n";
}
```

I'm looking for the Rust equivalent of this. Currently, I have the following idea:

```
let mut v: Vec<Box<Fn() -> i32>> = vec![];
for i in 1..6 {
   v.push((|i| {Box::new(move || i)})(i));
}

for f in v {
   println!("{}", f());
}
```

It works correctly, but I'm not sure whether it is the preferred way. Is calling a helper function really needed to achieve this or is there a more idiomatic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just:

```
v.push(Box::new(move || i));
```

A complete demo:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<Fn() -> i32>> = vec![];
    for i in 1..6 {
        v.push(Box::new(move || i));
    }

    for f in v {
        println!("{}", f());
    }
}
```